# Bootstrap table overflowing parent css

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap row containing among other things a div with a table inside. For an unknown reason I can't manage to make the table stop overflowing the parent. The table always overflow when I use a height of 100%. However it works if the parent div has a specific height.

```
 <div id="itemDetails">
 <div class="row">
    <article id="itemImage" class="col-md-2">
        ...
    </article>
    <article id="details" class="col-md-3">
        ...
    </article>
    <aside id="contributions" class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-2 well well-lg">
        <h4 translate="" class="ng-scope">contributions</h4>
        <!-- ngIf: !vm.data.anyContributions -->
        <div id="contTable">
            <!-- ngIf: vm.data.anyContributions --><table ng-if="vm.data.anyContributions"    class="table ng-scope">
                <tbody>
                    <!-- ngRepeat: contribution in vm.data.contributions -->
                    <tr>.......</tr>
                    .
                    <tr>.......</tr>
                </tbody>
            </table><!-- end ngIf: vm.data.anyContributions -->
        </div>
    </aside>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the related sass code

```
#itemDetails {

   height:100vh;

   div:first-child {
      height:45%;
   }
}
}

#contributions {

    max-height: 100%;

    #contTable {
      height: 100%;
      overflow: auto;
    }

    table {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }

}
```

[image]

Edit

I just did a codepen ilustrating the problem http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPbVEZ . As you can see I managed to hide the overflow of the table but I cannot manage to add some padding between the aside bottom and the table

Comment: Can you prepare a demo with just the static html and css

Comment: Like many case with css and big pages I didn't manage yet to reproduce it with only the essential pieces. I just need some ideas or suggestion about what could be wrong

Comment: Have you tried a `<div style='clear:both;'></div>` at the bottom of your contTable div?

Comment: It seems like an issue of floating container with non floating content.

Comment: edited with a codepen